# не удается создать проект react. Хотя node.js установлен

Tags: reactjs

введите сюда описание изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620780/cant-install-any-npm-package-error-4058